# What is the smallest unit of Monero called?

Tags: change

Satoshi Nakamoto invented Bitcoin, and the smallest unit of Bitcoin (10e-8 BTC) is a Satoshi.

If [**Nicolas van Saberhagen**](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf) authored Cryptonote, should the smallest unit of Monero (10e-12 XMR) be called a **Saint Nic** or **Pico**?

Answer (score 9):

The common usage is SI prefixes, with the first "mo" removed for ease of use (I forget the name of this speech concept).
This was proposed by David Latapie, an early Monero core team member, though the blog post explaining those is now 404.

Here's an overview of all common Monero units taken from the official [MoneroPedia](https://getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/denominations.html):

[image]

So 1 monero is 1000 millinero, 1e6 micronero, 1e9 nanonero, 1e12 piconero.

If you're rich, you'd also have kilonero, meganero..

Comment: That's too many syllables though, I'd actually prefer it exactly the other way round:
Decimon, Centimon, Millimon, Micromon, Nanomon (especially Nanonero is silly), Picomon (gotta catch them all).

Comment: @user2316370 Monmon.